# "the package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml" in simple Eclipse learning example

Tags: eclipse, soap

[Button disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPvjg.jpg) [Attached another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/742D7.jpg)
[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWPvM.jpg)

I am new to Eclipse and trying to create a simple SOAP Web service (like "Hello") according to Eclipse manual. All code is generated automatically.

In the generated Client code (xxxServiceLocator, xxxServiceBindingStub) I see the error
"the package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml" in lines like
oper.setReturnType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));

There are many questions and answers in StackOverflow, related to this questions, but i cannot find a simple recommendation: what to do by means of Eclipse IDE.

Is there a solution that a dummy like me can use?

Re-created the Client with different options. Did not touch the Client code since it was generated automatically.

Comment: What example are you following?

Comment: Which manual do you follow? It seems it is for Java 8. So you can use Java 8 or follow newer instructions for Java 9 or higher.

Comment: I followed the instructions from https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Implementing_a_Simple_Web_Service.pdf
Also there are multiple youtube resources for beginners, like 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKlVew0-GGQ
Procedure is the same, as well as the error.
I did not mention: I am in MacOS, but I am sure it does not matter

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is new since Java 9.  The general idea is that if you have a jar file that is a dependency that has classes in package "javax.xml.namespace", then that is the ONLY jar file that can contain classes in that package.  This is all related to the overall "module" feature of Java 9.

It isn't just "javax.xml.namespace" that this will occur with, although that one particular package is a common one to see this happen with.

Fixing this problem can be a little frustrating, partially because the error message is saying that SOME jar file is violating this rule, but it's not telling you which one.  What you have to do is figure out what jar file is violating this rule.  Hopefully, you can just remove that jar from your dependencies.  This is actually pretty common, as there tends to be duplicate copies of the classes in that namespace.  If that dependency actually has classes that you require, then more serious surgery would be required, perhaps simply removing the classes in the "javax.xml.namespace" package and leaving everything else.

I know of one way to find the jar that is violating this rule, and it's not very fancy, and it could potentially be somewhat painful.  The simple thing to do is to simply do the "Open Type" function in Eclipse and then enter "javax.xml.namespace" in the filter.  That will give you a long list of completion candidates for multiple jar files.  What you have to do is simply go through that list.  The class file entry also lists what jar file it's from.  For a particular entry, it's from the JDK or from an "official" jar file for that package, then you can ignore it.  What you're looking for is occurrences of those classes in "odd" jar files that don't look like the "official" source.  For each one of those, check to see if that jar file is actually a dependency of your project.  If so, that jar file is a candidate for removal or pruning. First try just removing it.  If that causes other errors, then you'll have to suit up for some more serious surgery.

Comment: Thank you David,
Invoking "Open Type" shows following lines in the list:

1) javax.xml.namespace - this is the one that is accessible from more than one module

package javax.xml.stream.events;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName; // This is the class in the code on which compiler complains

2) NamespaceContext

3) javax.xml.rpc.NamespaceConstants - is this the culprit?

Anyway, any ideas of whom should I remove and how?

Comment: You're missing the point. The point is to examine the jar files that come up in the list, not the class names.

Comment: I am missing something else. When I select "Open Type" and enter "javax.xml.namespace" I see only following in the list I see only those classes/interfaces: NameSpace, NameSpaceConstants and NameSpaceContext. The only mentioning of JARs is:  NameSpaceConstants corresponds to (referred by?) jaxrpc.jar, where actually QNames class is defined

Comment: Update your post with a picture of that dialog showing that result. Also, how are you specifying your dependencies?  Does it use a standard Maven pom.xml, or you storing jars directly in your project and hardcoding the dependencies in "Build Path"?

Comment: I added screenshot with Open Type dialog. As for dependensies: everything was created automatically. I selected File>New>Dynamic Web Project. Unfortunately I do not have deeper expertise.

Comment: I meant to update the original posting with that screenshot. I don't know where you put it, but it's not there.

Comment: Sorry, I hope I managed to attach the screenshot now.

Comment: Ok, please change the text in the filter to "javax.xml.namespace." (add a period to the end), and replace the screenshot with a screenshot of that.  It definitely appears that your "jaxrpc.jar" dependency is the problem. Along with providing that additional screenshot, you should try temporarily removing that "jaxrpc.jar" from your Build Path (don't remove the jar) and see if that gives you any errors.

Comment: Result of entering "javax.xml.namespace." is in "Attached another screenshot" I am not sure it provides more information.
As for removing that "jaxrpc.jar" from your Build Path: could you instruct me how to do it? Sorry, I started using Eclipse several days ago

Comment: In the "Project Properties", in the "Java Build Path" entry, there will be a "Libraries" tab. In that list, you will have an entry for that "jaxrpc" artifact. Select it, and click "Remove".

Comment: Button 'Remove' disabled. See screenshot "Button disabled". Enabled only when I select the whole "Java App Libraries", which I think is not good.

Comment: As it's in the "Web App Libraries" section, perhaps you have that library listed in your web.xml?  It's been years since I've worked on a pure JEE webapp. I think that's where it would be.

Comment: There are 7 web.xml files, all in Tomcat. None of them contains ""jaxrpc"
Well, I am afraid it is time to drop those efforts. Apparently the manual I am trying to use is outdated and with modern version of Eclipse I need something else.